# Question regarding the requirement (determinant) for implicit function theorem

Tags: multivariable-calculus, determinant, implicit-differentiation, implicit-function-theorem

[image]

The picture gives part of the definition for Implicit Function Theorem, I know some definition for determinants where there is linear independence between each equation in $\mathbb{R^k}$. However, other than that, I cannot seem to connect why det$D_y$F(a,b) cannot equal to 0 in order for $F(x,y)=0$

Comment: could you perhaps clarify/elaborate on what you mean by "I cannot seem to connect why det$D_y$F(a,b) cannot equal to 0 in order for $F(x,y)=0$"? because I think I might understand what you mean but I just want to be $100$ percent sure what your confusion is before answering

Comment: Yes! I can't understand why $det_F(a,b)$ cannot equal 0 is a requirement for the implicit function theorem to be applied. Is that still too vague? Let me know!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I'll provide is a motivation for why we might impose/how we might come up with the condition $\det (D_yF(a,b)) \neq 0$. For the full explanation of where this fact is used, of course just refer to the proof in your book.

I hope you know that differential calculus (roughly speaking) is the theory of **locally approximating by linear functions**, because linear things are nice to work with. So the key idea behind things like implicit function theorem/inverse function theorem or really any "big" theorem in differential calculus is to say to yourself

> "Right now I have a very general and difficult problem. Can I solve this problem in the special case where everything is nice and linear? Can I then use the insight I gained from the linear case to solve the general case?"

So, in the spirit of this guiding principle, we consider a very special case: let $A \in M_{k \times n}(\Bbb{R})$, and let $B \in M_{k \times k}(\Bbb{R})$, and define the function $G: \Bbb{R}^n \times \Bbb{R}^k \to \Bbb{R}^k$ by
\begin{equation}
G(x,y) = Ax + By
\end{equation}
Now the question at hand is: If $G(x,y) = 0$, then can I solve $y$ in terms of $x$? The answer is pretty simple in this case, because if the matrix $B$ is invertible (i.e $\det B \neq 0$) then
\begin{equation}
G(x,y) = 0
\end{equation}
implies that
\begin{align}
Ax + By = 0,
\end{align}
and hence
\begin{align}
y =- (B^{-1}A)  x.
\end{align}

So, to solve the problem in this special case, we had to make the assumption that $B$ is invertible (i.e $\det B \neq 0$). This is the key insight we gained by solving the special linear case!

This is useful because in general the function $F$ you have been given in the theorem might be very complicated, so you don't know what it really looks like. However, near a point $(a,b)$, where $F(a,b) = 0$, we can use the power of differential calculus to say
\begin{align}
F(x,y) \approx D_xF(a,b) \cdot (x-a) + D_yF(a,b) \cdot (y-b) \quad \text{if $(x,y)$ is near $(a,b)$} \tag{$*$}
\end{align}
(the approximation being better the closer $(x,y)$ is to $(a,b)$)

Now, the actual question you're being asked is: if $F(x,y) = 0$, then can we solve for $y$ in terms of $x$ (atleast for $(x,y)$ close to $(a,b)$)? This is a difficult problem, but we can use the linear approximation ($*$) to get a rough idea: we have that
\begin{align}
0 &= F(x,y) \\
& \approx D_xF(a,b) \cdot (x-a) + D_yF(a,b) \cdot (y-b)
\end{align}
Notice how this is almost like the situation we had above with the function $G$. Here, $A = D_xF(a,b)$ and $B = D_yF(a,b)$. So, if in this general case we **impose the condition** that $D_yF(a,b)$ is invertible (i.e its determinant is nonzero), then, we get
\begin{align}
y \approx - (D_yF(a,b))^{-1} \cdot D_xF(a,b) \cdot (x-a) + b
\end{align}

Thus, we have used our knowledge of the exact solution in the special linearized case to get a "rough approximate solution" in the general case. Now, all that remains to rigorously prove the theorem is to do some detailed and technical analysis of all the error terms wherever I said $\approx$ above, and to show that even in the general case, we really can solve for $y$ in terms of $x$, provided that $D_yF(a,b)$ is invertible (your book should cover all the detailed arguments).

This is the motivation for why we put $\det D_yF(a,b) \neq 0$ as part of our hypothesis, and it also outlines the thought process of how one might come up with such a requirement. Of course, after coming up with such a requirement, one can come up with examples to show that if this condition is not satisfied, then we cannot solve for $y$ in terms of $x$.

---

Indeed a simple example to show that the assumption $\det D_yF(a,b) \neq 0$ is needed for the theorem to be true is the following:

let $k=n=1$, define $F: \Bbb{R} \times \Bbb{R} \to \Bbb{R}$ by $F(x,y) = x^2 + y^2 - 1$. Choose $(a,b) = (1,0)$. Then, clearly $F(1,0) = 0$ and $D_yF(1,0) = 0$ (this is a $1 \times 1$ matrix). So, the determinant is also $0$.

Now, notice that the set of $(x,y)$ which satisfy $F(x,y) = 0$ are points on the unit circle in the plane. It should be clear pictorially, that near $(1,0)$, it is **impossible** to solve for $y$ as a function of $x$.

It was not possible in this case because the determinant was $0$. This shows why the determinant condition is required. (However, notice that $D_xF(1,0) = 2 \neq 0$, so we can solve for $x$ as a function of $y$)

---

**Edit in response to comments:**

Recall that in general, by definition, for any function $F: \Bbb{R}^p \to \Bbb{R}^m$, we say $F$ is differentiable at $\alpha$, if there is an $n \times p$ matrix $T$ such that
\begin{equation}
F(\xi) - F(\alpha) = T(\xi - \alpha) + o(\lVert\xi - \alpha \rVert) 
\end{equation}
If $F$ is differentiable at $\alpha$, then $T$ is unique, and we denote it by the symbol $DF(\alpha)$.
i.e we can approximate the change $F(\xi)-F(\alpha)$ by a linear part $DF(\alpha) \cdot (\xi -\alpha)$, and the approximation is valid up to an accuracy of little-oh.

In your particular case, write $p = n+k$, $\xi = \begin{bmatrix} x \\y \end{bmatrix} $, and write $\alpha = (a,b)$. Note that we have the following block matrix decomposition:
\begin{align}
DF(a,b) = 
\begin{bmatrix}
D_xF(a,b) & D_yF(a,b)
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}
Hence, we get
\begin{align}
F(x,y) &= F(a,b) + DF(a,b) \cdot
\begin{bmatrix}
x-a \\
y-b
\end{bmatrix}
+ o(\lVert (x,y) - (a,b)\rVert) \\
&= F(a,b) + 
\begin{bmatrix}
D_xF(a,b) & D_yF(a,b)
\end{bmatrix}
\cdot
\begin{bmatrix}
x-a \\
y-b
\end{bmatrix}
+ o(\lVert (x,y) - (a,b)\rVert) \\
&= F(a,b) + D_xF(a,b) \cdot (x-a) + D_yF(a,b) \cdot (y-b) +  o(\lVert (x,y) - (a,b)\rVert)
\end{align}

This is the proper statement in general, and everything is an equal sign (there are no approximations, because we already took the error term into account with the little-oh notation). In the case of the implicit function theorem, we have $F(a,b) = 0$ by assumption. Hence, we get the statement
\begin{equation}
F(x,y) = D_xF(a,b) \cdot (x-a) + D_yF(a,b) \cdot (y-b) +  o(\lVert (x,y) - (a,b)\rVert)
\end{equation}

(In my above explanation, I was too lazy to carry around the little-oh, so I just wrote $\approx$ everywhere instead)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the thorough explanation, I understand now. However, I don't quite get why this approximation, (,)≈(,)⋅+(,)⋅ makes sense. I used an example in just one dimension for the domain and range where $f(x) = x^2$, then if we let x = 7, $f'(6.99)⋅7$ would be nowhere close f(7). Am I using a relevant comparison?

Comment: you're right, there's a typo there, I'll fix it. But to make the comparison clear, try something with two dimensions in the domain, and one dimension in the target space

Comment: For instance, try the one at the end, where $F(x,y) = x^2 + y^2 -1$, with $(a,b) = (1,0)$. Then, $F(a,b) = 0$ is clear. What I'm saying is that $F(x,y) \approx D_xF(a,b) \cdot (x-a) + D_yF(a,b) (y-b)$, which in this case simplifies to $F(x,y) \approx 2(x-1) + 0$. So try computing $F(0.9,0.1)$ exactly, and approximately. The exact answer is $-0.18$, the approximate answer is $-0.2$, so you can see they are indeed close.

Comment: @JohnnyYang If you want to see a proper proof of that fact in the general case, let me know; I'll edit my answer appropriately.

Comment: Ohh I see, and I tried using the same example you used but instead with $(a,b) = (10, 12)$ and $(x,y) = (9.99, 11.99)$. I found that the closer $x$ and $y$ are to $a$ and $b$, the further the approximation is when I plug in the computed values. Maybe seeing the general proof will help me to visualize how the approximation work better?

Comment: @Johnny Yang in this specific case, add $F(a, b) $ to your approximation. Then everything should work nicely. Notice that in my specific choice of $(a, b)$, this term was 0. Sure, I'll edit my answer later

Comment: @JohnnyYang I have edited the answer to include the justification for the approximation

Comment: I get it now, thank you!!